# Convergence of the distributions function by Kolmogorov distance.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence

Let $X_{k+1}$ be random variable define as
\begin{align*}
X_{k+1}=
\begin{cases}
f(X_k)=\frac{X_k}{2} & \text{ with prob. } \frac{1}{2},\\
g(X_k)=\frac{X_k+1}{2} & \text{ with prob. } \frac{1}{2},
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
where $k=0,1,2,3,\dots$ and $X_0=x_0$ with probability $1$ and $x_0\in\left<0,1\right)$.

How to proof that
\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\left(\sup_{x\in\left<0,1\right)}|F_{X_k}(x)-G_{\mathscr{U}}(x)|\right)=0, \tag{1}
\end{align}
where $G_{\mathscr{U}}(x)$ is distribution function of uniform distribution on the interval $\left<0,1\right)$.

I have already proved $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}F_{X_k}(x)=G_{\mathscr{U}}(x)$ but I have used little bit long and complicated way. I have found out distribution function of $X_k$ in general and then computed characteristic function of $X_k$ and finally computed limit of this characteristic function and shown that it is the same as characteristic function of the uniform distribution on $\left<0,1\right>$.

I would like to see some short and nice way how to prove especially $(1)$ because than convergence by distribution implies from it. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Also I have been trying to show that $P\left(X_k\in\left(\frac{i}{2^k},\frac{i+1}{2^k}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{2^k}$, for $i=0,1,2,\dots,2^k-1$ and it should be enough for the $(1)$.

EDIT:

I have already prooved that $P\left(X_k\in\left(\frac{i}{2^k},\frac{i+1}{2^k}\right)\right)=\frac{1}{2^k}$ how it can be use for problem $(1)$?